# A Function that’s dedicated to adding the event listener to the newly created button

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener, event-listener, iife

I'm trying to create a function that is dedicated to adding the event listener to the newly created button.

I'm currently taking a course and I can't seem to understand this part:

> "Optional (Advanced): You may choose to have another function that’s
> dedicated to adding the event listener to the newly created button
> rather than including the code inside the addListItem() function. If
> you do so, you’ll have to pass two parameters to the new function—the
> first is the variable referring to the button (to add the event
> listener to it), and the second is the Pokémon object, which is
> necessary to call showDetails in the event handler from there.
> Finally, call that new function inside addListItem() after the button
> is appended to the DOM."

Here is a snippet of what I came up with:

```js
 function eventListener(button, pokemon) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
      showDetails(pokemon);
    });
  }
```

I recommend checking out the full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/event-listener-lm16im

Comment: "*I'm trying to create a function*" - and it seems you succeeded. What do you think is left unclear?

Comment: Your code sandbox link doesn't work/doesn't show the code you're talking about (that's why it's often best to keep your code self contained within the question using code snippets. If it's too large, it's a good idea to create a [mre] of your issue).

Comment: @bergi sorry for not being clear enough. I want that when I click on the button I created I could see the objects in the console

Comment: @Brayan It should do that. If it doesn't, show us how you're calling `eventListener` and what `showDetails` is.

Answer (score 0):

All that function is doing is taking reference of a button and data to display, add 'click' event listener on that button and call showDetails() function when that button is clicked.

Here, I have created demo for you to understand how it works

https://jsfiddle.net/6jhmaz8x/1/

HTML file

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="newButton">
      Create new button
    </button>
    <div id="container">
      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS File:

```
function eventListener(button, pokemon) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    showDetails(pokemon);
  });
}
  
function showDetails(pokemon){
    console.log(pokemon)
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.getElementById('newButton').addEventListener('click',()=>{
      let button = document.createElement('button');
      button.type = 'button';
      button.innerHTML = 'Show details';
      document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button)
      let pokemon = 'this is pokemon'
      eventListener(button,pokemon)
    })
});
```